# How to intercept data transmission on a LAN?

Tags: networking, man-in-the-middle

I have a piece of electrical hardware (a power inverter) which is hard wired to my router and transmits usage data to a third party vendor at regular intervals. The vendor provides a convenient web interface for users to view charts of their data and even make adjustments to settings.

As nice as this is, I'd rather not be 100% reliant on a third party website to view my own usage data. It also bothers me that I really have no control over where and when this data is sent, or even any direct knowledge about *what* is being sent. I'd like to somehow intercept that data to see for myself what it is sending and store it in my own database. I guess this is similar to a man-in-the-middle attack, except that I'm not attacking and I am the owner of the data in question.

I have a moderate amount of experience working with APIs but not much experience at all with networking hardware. Is what I'm trying to do possible? How can it be done?

**UPDATE:**

The inverter uses a DB9 port dongle with model number EESE-D200. The dongle looks like this:

[image]

Comment: If your router supports it, you could enable a "mirror port" that copies all traffic on the inverter port to that mirror port. You could use a tool like Wireshark to analyze its traffic. I have no idea if your router supports this though. When you say "hard wired to my router", do you mean there's really no way to disconnect it or to redirect its traffic through another device?

Comment: Depending on the equipment this may not be possible (if its sending over HTTPS and validates the certificate, which is a reasonably common pattern).  Without knowing more about your equipment/setup its hard to advise. Seasoned admins using decent routers can sniff this on the router.  Alternatively you could create a bridge between 2 nics, or even connect it so it routes traffic via a PC which is acting as a router.

Comment: @StarCat - by "hard wired" I mean it's plugged in with a physical ethernet cable - not transmitting over wireless. For purposes of answering this question, please assume that I am willing to purchase and use whatever hardware is required to solve the problem.

Comment: @davidgo - (see above comment). The router is an old Airport Extreme.  As mentioned above I am open to changing this configuration. I realize https may present a challenge - at the moment we really have no idea how it connects so I can't say.

Comment: There is no trivial way to do this - At minimum you will need a dump of the data flow, and realistically you will want to intercept it.  This means implementing hardware to do this. Among other solutions, this could be done using a router with ddwrt on it, or configuring a computer as a router - I know how to do this in Linux, but not Windows or mac.  That said there is a version  of libpcap (used to capture packets) for the Mac so this is likely possible, but quite involved.

Comment: @davidgo - I do have a linux box running on the LAN that could be (re)purposed for that use. Would you mind at least adding what you've written above as an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: If the Ethernet connection is only 100Base-T (and not Gigabit), and you can obtain a (real) Ethernet hub (not a switch), then that is the simplest method of snooping the traffic.  Beware of some "hubs" that are mislabeled and are actually switches.  Wireshark documentation describes that problem.

Comment: @sawdust - router is 4th Gen Airport Extreme which does indeed have Gigabit ethernet. Does that rule out your idea? As mentioned above, I'd be open to routing my device through additional hardware if needed.

Comment: Yeah, a gigabit ethernet device will almost certainly be a switch - indeed most 100 megabit things would be switches as well.  You would be hard pressed to find a hub nowadays - but if you can its a good idea.

Comment: You could limit the Ethernet speed just to this power inverter with a 100 Mbps hub.  Is this power inverter even capable of Gbit?  Note that a lot of industrial/commercial devices that have an Ethernet connection are still only capable of 100Mbps.

Comment: @sawdust - not sure what it's capable of. I updated the question with a bit more info on the connector.  Would you mind adding an answer with a bit more detail on how to achieve this using an ethernet hub?

Comment: A DB-9 connector is typically used for RS-232 and not Ethernet.  What does this *"dongle"* have to do with the *"power inverter"* and a network connection???  Instead of just a *"model number"*, provide the manufacturer's name! If this *"power inverter"* has any network capability, then that would clearly be listed in its specifications. RTM!

Comment: Why are you using *"quotation marks"* and trippple question marks??? And exclamation marks in your question! The *"dongle"* is plugged in to the *"inverter"* and the *"ethernet cable"* is wired to the dongle. Presumably the inverter communicates to the dongle which then provides a gateway to communicate to the LAN. The dongle manufacturer is not specified anywhere on it. I don't see how knowing the inverter manufacturer is going to help you answer this question, but since you asked it's [Sol-Ark](https://www.sol-ark.com/sol-ark-12k-all-in-one)! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Linux box is a great tool to use to intercept data.   The ideal is to have 2 network ports and intercept data which is going between them - although it is likely doable with a single port and some creative network setup.  There are multiple solutions and variants on the theme - this is 1 possibility:

Step 1 - configure your interfaces

1. Configure your Linux box with 2 IP addresses.  If you have an ethernet and WIFI connection, use the WIFI connection for your Internet traffic as you do at the moment and plug the inverter ethet into the ethernet port, then reconfigure the ethernet interface with a static IP address you are not using in your network.  (The IP range 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 is usually a good choice - below I'll assume you have configured the ethernet port on 172.16.0.1)    OR
2. If you have 2 ethernet connections, do the same thing as above, using 1 connection for your Internet and the other for the Inverter OR
3. If you only have 1 ethernet connection things are a bit harder. You will need to bring up 2 virtual interfaces on the same ethernet connection.  This is doable with a command like ip addr add 172.160.0.1/24 dev eth0
4. Reconfigure the Inverter with a static IP address on your new network with a gateway out your Linux box (eg 172.16.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 or /24, gateway 172.16.0.1.  You can use any working DNS server you like - I use 1.1.1.1.)

Step 2 - Make the Linux box do routing.

5. Enable forwarding with commands like

   sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
6. Set up Network address translation.  (Double NAT is yuk but easy, and likely good-enough here) with a command like below.  You will need to change the wlan0 to the address of your interfaces (wlan = WIFI, eth0 = ethernet device is plugged into here)

   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
   iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT

At this point, and some luck your Inverter should be able to reach the Internet through your Linux box.

Step 3 - Intercept traffic

There is no single solution here, but you can start with a command like
tcpdump -nX -i eth0 src or dst 172.16.0.2
Which will dump all traffic traversing eth0 with the src or IP address 172.16.0.2 as both hex and readable traffic.

Another version, for example, will dump DNS traffic in an easily readable form -
tcpdump -i eth0 src or dst 172.16.0.2 and port 53

Comment: Wow David - there's a lot to digest here. Although I'm probably a long way off from actually implementing any of this, I'm accepting your answer on the basis that covers all the bases.  I'll follow up at some point to let you know how things go.  Thanks so much!